# Use coffeescript/javascript 'throw error' or 'throw new Error(error)'?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, coffeescript

I have the following coffeescript code:

```
try
   do something
catch error
   log something
   throw error
```

Should I use `throw new Error(error)` instead of `throw error`?

What is the difference?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Same as in other languages like C# or Java:

- `throw error` throws the same Error object
- `throw new Error(error)` wraps it into a new Error object. The later is used, for example, in Java when you need to convert [checked Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explaination) into unchecked one. In JavaScript you don't need to wrap exceptions as this would make stacktrace a bit longer and less pretty.

**Edit**: There're some security implications as well. Here's an example:

```
function noWrap() {
    try {
        var o = {}; o.nonexistingMethod();
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}

function wrap() {
    try {
        var o = {}; o.nonexistingMethod();
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
}
```

Calling `noWrap()` produces the following error message:

```
"TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'nonexistingMethod'"
// with error.arguments === ['nonexistingMethod', o]
```

Calling `wrap()` produces the following error message:

```
"Error: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'nonexistingMethod'"
//  with error.arguments === undefined
```

So, as you can see by using a wrapping Error object we can hide the `arguments` of original error. Suppose you're writing one of the following:

- some kind of a library
- a script which will be loaded on a page that you don't own (for example, some kind of like or tweet button)
- a script on a page that has some third-party scripts loaded (social buttons, ads, tracking code, etc.)

In all those cases listed above in order to stay secure *you should wrap your* `Error` *objects*. Otherwise you may accidentally leak references to your internal objects, functions and variables.

**Edit 2**: Regarding stacktraces. Both variants preserve them. Here's [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/listochkin/tJzCF/) and I get the following stacktraces in Chrome:

```
// No wrapping:
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'nonexistingMethod'
    at noWrap (http://fiddle.jshell.net/listochkin/tJzCF/show/:22:23)
    at http://fiddle.jshell.net/listochkin/tJzCF/show/:37:5
    at http://fiddle.jshell.net/js/lib/mootools-core-1.4.5-nocompat.js:3901:62
    at http://fiddle.jshell.net/js/lib/mootools-core-1.4.5-nocompat.js:3915:20

// Wrapping:
Error: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'nonexistingMethod'
    at wrap (http://fiddle.jshell.net/listochkin/tJzCF/show/:32:15)
    at http://fiddle.jshell.net/listochkin/tJzCF/show/:44:5
    at http://fiddle.jshell.net/js/lib/mootools-core-1.4.5-nocompat.js:3901:62
    at http://fiddle.jshell.net/js/lib/mootools-core-1.4.5-nocompat.js:3915:20
```

Comment: Someone advised me that the wrapped version gives you an error object with a full stacktrace, otherwise you only get the error message.

Comment: He claims that you get the stacktrace because you use console.error(), if you want to pass the error object somewhere else, you loose them. I tend to believe that they get preserved, but it will be interesting to investigate this.

Comment: It's browser-dependent. For example, In IE9 there's no `stack` property on Error objects. I don't know about other browsers.